# Are the rings $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<(x+1)^3>$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<x^3>$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Are the quotient rings $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<(x+1)^3>$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<x^3>$ isomorphic?

**Attempt.** They are both not integral domains, they are commutative and they both have $4$ revertible elements. I think that they are isomophic, but both the use of the first isomoprhism theorem and the construction of an isomoprhism from the scratch seem to bring me some difficulties.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The map $x\mapsto x+1$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: rename $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^3)$ to $\Bbb Z[y]/(y^3)$ to make it easier to avoid confusion. Then consider the homomorphism that sends $y$ to $x+1$ (and $1$ to $1$).

Comment: So you are proposing to take $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<x^3>\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<(x+1)^3>: ~\phi(f(x)+<x^3>):=f(x+1)+<(x+1)^3>$?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Yeah, that's what I'm proposing. You have to show that it is well-defined, of course, and then that it is bijective. I suggest you do that by looking at the map $\Bbb Z[y]\to \Bbb Z[x]/((x+1)^3)$ given by $f(y)\mapsto f(x+1) + ((x+1)^3)$, which is clearly well-defined, and check that it is surjective, and what its kernel is.