# Are the quotient rings $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\left<x^2\right>$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\left<x^2 + 1\right>$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Are the quotient rings $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\left<x^2\right>$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\left<x^2 + 1\right>$ isomorphic?

**Attempt.** 
I think they are isomorphic.

I have thought it extensively. I have supposed a isomorphic function $\phi$ as follows.

$\phi (x + 1)  \to  x$

$\phi  (x) \to  (x + 1)$

$\phi  (1) \to  1$

$\phi  (0) \to  0$

Then I verified in brute force manner that the mapping is homomorphic.

Can anyone please tell me if I have gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: That's fine: note that $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ over $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: Yea I know..Is there any better way to solve it ? I have to verify 20 times to know that they are ring homomorphic.@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Have a look at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551806/are-the-rings-mathbbz-2x-x13-and-mathbbz-2x-x3-isomorphic?rq=1); replace $x^3$ by $x^2$ in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Your brute force approach is fine. Alternatively, note that the map
$$\Bbb{Z}_2[x]\ \longmapsto\ \Bbb{Z}_2[x]:\ x\ \longmapsto\ x+1,$$
is a ring isomorphism. The preimage of the ideal $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is then
$$\langle (x-1)^2+1\rangle=\langle x^2\rangle,$$
from which it follows that the corresponding quotients are isomorphic.